# Php code to print alternate addition and subtraction sequence

Tags: php, series

How to print sequence 36 31 29 24 22 17 15 in php

It is in -5,-2 pattern

Answer (score 1):

You should alternate the decrement value

```
$start = 36;
$end = 15;
$x = $start;
$delta = 5;
while ($x >= $end)
{
    echo "$x<BR>";
    $x = $x - $delta;
    if ($delta == 5)
        $delta=2;
    else
        $delta=5;
}
```